# SOQL Results differ from Salesforce Report

Tags: soql, query, opportunity-lineitem, conga, opp-lineitemschedule

I have an SOQL query for a Conga button which gives different results from a Salesforce report that has the same filter criteria as the query.  Both CongaPete and I are baffled but I don't have Premier Support for 'developer' type cases so I've been directed here to the 'community' to figure it out.

Has anyone here had a similar challenge or idea about how to overcome this one?

Comment: Are you getting more records in conga than report? If so answer given by Mukesh Verma is relevant. Conga get data from salesforce using api calls and as per salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_concepts_security.htm) all api calls respect the sharing model.

Answer (score 2):

This could be due to Organization-Wide Sharing Defaults. Reports strictly follows sharing settings. That means User can see only those records for which he/she has at least read access.
On the same side custom solutions like apex classes /api do have options to override sharing setting. They have option to pull all records irrespective of sharing setting. If some custom apex classes are involved, please make sure they are using `with sharing` keyword.

Comment: Thanks Mukesh, I'll see if that helps - do you know if SOQL has a respect sharing settings equivalent?